# Python - Check which child class is being used

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a Python Tkinter GUI where I have two classes, they're called `temperatureWidget` and `lightWidget` both of which extend their parent called `Widget`. In the parent class I have a Entry and a button which is linked to a function called `setSensors()`. Within this function I want to check which subclass is being used. So say for instance if the subclass is `temperatureWidget` then read the input of the scale called "temperatureSlider" and put the value of that in the label called "Temperature label" This may be very vague but the code will clarify

```
import random
# from random import *
from tkinter import *
import threading
from queue import *
import datetime

import matplotlib as matplotlib

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="white")
root.title("Project 2.1")


class SerialThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Random most secnificant bit tussen 0 en 1
        self.msb = random.randint(0, 1)
        # Lijst met widgets
        self.widgets = []
        # De root
        self.master = master
        # Zet het scherm volledige scherm
        self.master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()))

        # Maak een nieuwe frame aan
        self.widgetFrame = Frame(master, bg="white")
        # En zet deze frame boven aan de pagina
        self.widgetFrame.pack(side=TOP)

        # Maak een nieuwe frame aan en zet deze in de widgetFrame
        self.widgetTop = Frame(self.widgetFrame, bg="white")
        # Zet deze frame bovenaan in de widgetframe
        self.widgetTop.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        #
        self.removeText = Entry(self.widgetTop)
        self.removeText.pack()
        removeButton = Button(self.widgetTop, text="Remove widget ", command=self.removeWidget)
        removeButton.pack()

        addButton = Button(self.widgetTop, text="Add widget", command=self.addWidgetToScreen)
        addButton.pack()

    def showGui(self):
        # Als de lengte van de lijst met widgets groter is dan 0
        if len(self.widgets):
            # Voor alle widgets in de lijst met widgets
            for widget in range(len(self.widgets)):
                # Stop de widget in de mainframe
                self.widgets[widget].mainFrame.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20, padx=20, fill=Y)
        # Anders
        else:
            # Laat deze label zien
            NoInputLabel = Label(self.widgetTop, text="No modules connected, please connect a module",
                                 font='Helvetica 16 bold', bg='white', anchor='center')
            NoInputLabel.pack(side=TOP, pady=50, padx=20)

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        # Voeg de widget toe aan de lijst met widgets
        self.widgets.append(widget)

    def removeWidget(self):
        # Voor alle widgets in de lijst met widgets
        for index, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            # Als de naam van de widget gelijk is aan de ingevulde naam
            if widget.name == self.removeText.get():
                # Verwijder dan die widget uit de mainframe
                self.widgets[index].mainFrame.pack_forget()
                # Em verwijder hem uit de lijst
                del self.widgets[index]

    def addWidgetToScreen(self):
        # Als de lengte van de widget groter is dan 0
        num = random.randint(0, 1)
        if len(self.widgets):

            if num == 0:
                # En maak een nieuwe widget aan met als nummer één hoger dan de laatste
                newWidget = temperatureWidget(self.master, "COM" + str(len(self.widgets) + 1), self)
            else:
                newWidget = lightWidget(self.master, "COM" + str(len(self.widgets) + 1), self)
        else:
            # Maak een widget aan met nummer 1
            if num == 0:
                # En maak een nieuwe widget aan met als nummer één hoger dan de laatste
                newWidget = temperatureWidget(self.master, "COM1", self)
            else:
                newWidget = lightWidget(self.master, "COM1", self)

        # Voeg hem dan toe aan de lijst met widgets
        self.widgets.append(newWidget)
        # Pak de widget in de mainframe
        self.widgets[-1].mainFrame.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20, padx=20, fill=Y)


class Widget:
    def __init__(self, master, name, gui):
        self.msb = 0
        self.master = master
        self.name = name
        self.gui = gui

        # Set de main frame van een widget
        self.mainFrame = Frame(gui.widgetFrame, bg='white')

        # Maak een frame die de top van de mainframe hanteerd
        self.mainFrameTop = Frame(self.mainFrame, bg='white')
        self.mainFrameTop.pack(side=TOP)
        # Maak een die onder de top frame komt en daarom center is
        self.mainFrameCenter = Frame(self.mainFrame, bg='white')
        self.mainFrameCenter.pack(side=TOP)
        # Maak een die daar weer onder komt en dus onderstaan zit
        self.mainFrameBottom = Frame(self.mainFrame, bg='white')
        self.mainFrameBottom.pack(side=TOP)

        colorArray = list(matplotlib.colors.cnames.values())

        self.WidgetName = Label(self.mainFrameTop, text=name, font='Helvetica 16 bold', bg=random.choice(colorArray))
        self.WidgetName.pack(fill=X)

        self.msb = random.randint(0, 1)

        self.maxRolloutPositionLabel = Label(self.mainFrameTop, text="Rolling distance (cm): ", bg="white")
        self.maxRolloutPositionLabel.pack()

        self.maxRolloutEntry = Entry(self.mainFrameTop, bg="white")
        self.maxRolloutEntry.pack()

        self.submitFormButton = Button(self.mainFrameTop, text="Submit", command=self.setSensors, bg="white")
        self.submitFormButton.pack()

        '''
            Sunblind status functions and GUI elements
        '''
        self.openSunblindButton = Button(self.mainFrameCenter, text="Open sunblind", command=self.openSunblind,
                                         state=NORMAL,
                                         bg="#28a745", fg="white")
        self.openSunblindButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.closeSunblindButton = Button(self.mainFrameCenter, text="Close sunblind", command=self.closeSunblind,
                                          state=NORMAL, bg="#dc3545", fg="white")
        self.closeSunblindButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.setSunblindStatusButton = Button(self.mainFrameCenter, text="Automatic", command=self.setSunblindStatus,
                                              bg="#6c757d", fg="white")
        self.setSunblindStatusButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.sunblindFrame = Frame(self.mainFrameBottom, bg="white")
        self.sunblindFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.sunblindStatusLabel = Label(self.sunblindFrame, text="Sunblind status:", bg="white", anchor="w")
        self.sunblindStatusLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5)
        self.sunblindStatus = Label(self.sunblindFrame, text="Manual", bg="white")
        self.sunblindStatus.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)

        self.rolloutFrame = Frame(self.mainFrameBottom, bg="white")
        self.rolloutFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.rolloutLabel = Label(self.rolloutFrame, text="Roll-out position: ", justify=LEFT, bg="white", anchor="w")
        self.rolloutLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5)
        self.rolloutValue = Label(self.rolloutFrame, text="", bg="white")
        self.rolloutValue.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)

        self.variable = StringVar(self.mainFrameBottom)
        self.variable.set(self.name)
        self.chooseArduino = OptionMenu(self.mainFrameBottom, self.variable, "Living Room", "Bedroom", "Study")
        self.chooseArduino.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.setNameButton = Button(self.mainFrameBottom, text="Set name", command=self.setArduinoName)
        self.setNameButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def setSensors(self):
        print("Set the temperature and light of the sensors")
        # Check which subclass is used
        self.maxRolloutPositionLabel.config(text="Rolling distance (cm): " + str(self.maxRolloutEntry.get()))


    def setName(self, widgetName):
        self.name = widgetName

    def openSunblind(self):
        print("Set the sunblind to an open state")
        self.rolloutValue.config(text="Rolled out")

    def closeSunblind(self):
        print("Set the sunblind to an closed state")
        self.rolloutValue.config(text="Rolled in")

    def setSunblindStatus(self):
        if self.setSunblindStatusButton.config('text')[-1] == 'Automatic':
            self.openSunblindButton.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.closeSunblindButton.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.setSunblindStatusButton.config(text='Manual')
            print("Sunblind is set to: " + self.setSunblindStatusButton['text'])
            self.sunblindStatus.config(text="Automatic")
            self.rolloutValue.config(text='')
        else:
            self.openSunblindButton.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.closeSunblindButton.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.setSunblindStatusButton.config(text='Automatic')
            print("Sunblind is set to: " + self.setSunblindStatusButton['text'])
            self.sunblindStatus.config(text="Manual")

    def setArduinoName(self):
        self.WidgetName.config(text=self.variable.get())

    def getTemperature(self):
        return self.temperature

    def getLightIntensity(self):
        return self.lightIntensity


class temperatureWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, master, name, gui):
        super().__init__(master, name, gui)

        self.temperatureSliderLabel = Label(self.mainFrameTop, text="Temperature (°C)", bg="white")
        self.temperatureSlider = Scale(self.mainFrameTop, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=250, from_=0, to=40, bg="white")
        self.temperatureSliderLabel.pack()
        self.temperatureSlider.pack()

        self.temperatureFrame = Frame(self.mainFrameBottom, bg="white")
        self.temperatureFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.temperatureValueLabel = Label(self.temperatureFrame, text="Temperature: ", justify=LEFT, bg="white",
                                           anchor="w")
        self.temperatureValue = Label(self.temperatureFrame, text="", bg="white")

        self.temperatureValueLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5)
        self.temperatureValue.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)


class lightWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, master, name, gui):
        super().__init__(master, name, gui)

        self.lightSliderLabel = Label(self.mainFrameTop, text="Light Intensity (%)", bg="white")
        self.lightSlider = Scale(self.mainFrameTop, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=250, bg="white")
        self.lightSliderLabel.pack()
        self.lightSlider.pack()

        self.lightSliderFrame = Frame(self.mainFrameBottom, bg="white")
        self.lightSliderFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.lightSliderValueLabel = Label(self.lightSliderFrame, text="Light Intensity: ", justify=LEFT,
                                           bg="white",
                                           anchor="w")
        self.lightSliderValue = Label(self.lightSliderFrame, text="", bg="white")
        self.lightSliderValueLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, fill=X)
        self.lightSliderValue.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)


Visueel = GUI(root)
Arduino1 = lightWidget(root, "COM1", Visueel)
Arduino2 = temperatureWidget(root, "COMT", Visueel)
Arduino3 = lightWidget(root, "COML", Visueel)
Arduino4 = temperatureWidget(root, "COM4", Visueel)
Arduino5 = lightWidget(root, "COM5", Visueel)

Visueel.addWidget(Arduino1)
Visueel.addWidget(Arduino2)
Visueel.addWidget(Arduino3)
Visueel.addWidget(Arduino4)
Visueel.addWidget(Arduino5)
Visueel.showGui()

root.mainloop()
```

I've searched for an answer for over an hour but can't seem to find one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check which class it is:

```
    def setSensors(self):
        print("Set the temperature and light of the sensors")
        # Check which subclass is used
        if isinstance(self, lightWidget):
            print(lightWidget.__name__)
        else:
            print(temperatureWidget.__name__)
        self.maxRolloutPositionLabel.config(text="Rolling distance (cm): " + str(self.maxRolloutEntry.get()))
```